# How to deploy angular app supporting ssl

Tags: angular, ssl, https, github-pages, deploying

This may seem like a dumb question but I am trying to host my angular website on github pages with a custom domain name and I want to use https but I can't figure out exactly how.

Am I supposed to write more code to handle https requests or do I simply need to add ssl keys and certs to the project and change some configurations?

Comment: By default github pages serves content on https. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: Thank you @Vikas786 all I had to do really is to remove the custom domain from github and add it back in and wait a bit. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And it turns out it was a dumb question. Nothing much needs to be done. Just upload your site with ngh, remove your custom domain and add it back, wait a bit and you should be in order :)